# HTML <select> element sends default selected even if un-selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ejs

I have a dropdown generated via EJS that sets the default `selected` value to whatever admin is currently in place for this company.

Users should be able to unselect the current admin and select a different one, removing the current admin as an admin for the company.

However selecting another option and/or CTRL+clicking the default option does not un-select it, and the form sends both the default option and whatever else may be selected.

Have I missed something in the way the `selected` attribute for an `option` works?

```html
<div id="adminDropdown">
  <% if (companyAdmins) { %>
    <select name="chooseAdmins" id="chooseAdmins" form="updateCompany" multiple class="form-control">
      <% for (let location of currentCompany.locations ) { %>
        <% for (let contact of location.contacts) { %> 
          <option value="<%= contact.id %>" <%= contact.isCompanyAdmin ? 'selected' : '' %>><%= contact.firstName %> <%= contact.lastName %></option>
        <% } %>
      <% } %>
    </select>
    <span class="muted"><small>Hold `CTRL` to select multiple admins, or to deselect an admin.<br />
      To add users to this list, first add them to their Location's "Contacts".
    </small></span>
  <% } else { %>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Error loading admins data</div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

Also, inspecting the element in chrome, the 'selected' attribute shows correctly on load, but doesn't go away after clicking or ctrl+clicking the option, like it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

The issue arises from duplicating the code shown for the `chooseAdmins` dropdown for another similar dropdown just below it where the user can choose a new default Location, where I didn't update the `name` or `id` attributes to be relevant to the new dropdown's content. So there wasn't really an error, `body-parser` was seeing two `select` elements with the same name, so it just combined the selected values for both into one array.

The more I learn, the more I understand how little I understand.

Answer (score 1):

The problem i see is that you don't close the first for loop inside select

```
<% for (let location of currentCompany.locations ) { %>
    <% for (let contact of location.contacts) { %> 
        <option value="<%= contact.id %>" <%= contact.isCompanyAdmin ? 'selected' : '' %>><%= `${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}` %></option>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

By the way, In my opinion using string literals inside ejs you only reduce the code readability.
 You can keep it simple `<%= contact.firstName %> <%= contact.lastName %>`

Comment: Good catch! However, still the same problem. I updated the question with the corrected syntax, and spread out the EJS as you suggested.